# JavaFx: Why dose 'Thread.sleep( )' stop UI threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

```
public void startApp(){
       primaryStage.show();
       new Thread(new Runnable(){
             public void run(){
                  Thread.sleep(20000);//2 seconds

                  //do something.........

                  System.out.println("all things done");
             }
       }).run();
}
```

I think primaryStage will show first.But, in fact, the primaryStage always shows after the new thread finished( after printing 'all things done'). If I delete 'Thread.sleep(20000)', the primaryStage also after 'all things done'. Why? Am I wrong somewhere?
Thank you all guys first!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> the primaryStage always shows after the **new thread** finished

You are NOT creating a new thread here. You are just calling the `run()` method on the Runnable object.

You need to use `.start()` instead of `.run()` for it to execute in a new thread.

Comment: Hi , I try this  program in my computer ,but it shows me that the ```primaryStage.show()``` is always execute first .Why ? Why my result is different from above situation ? Can you explain  it for us ? Thanks!

Comment: Is your `primaryStage.show()` actually an JavaFX `Stage#show()` method? Which displays the window? Or did you just create a random `show()` method and called it?

Comment: Cheers! It works perfectly for me! thanks for the great help!

Comment: Ok , I just get it , my method is not actually an JavaFX Stage show().Thanks for your help!

Comment: @uestcfei, just to make it clear, the `show()` method will be called first (just like any other method), but the window won't be displayed till the end because the EDT thread is blocked...

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.sleep(20000);//2 seconds` It's 20 seconds.

I have tried this code and it seem to work as you expected so the issue must be somewhere else. https://ideone.com/zEjT8Q

Comment: Thanks for your help, 'Codebender' solved my problem.(Ps: 'System.out.println("1")' is not on UI Thread. )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is like this :

```
public void startApp(){
    primaryStage.show();
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(20000);//2 seconds
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //do something.........

            System.out.println("all things done");

        }
    }).run();
}
```

You need to implement the method `run()` of `Runnable`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I made a mistake in the code in my questions and left out the method signature, I had actually overrride "run" method.